# Ajax only loading first record?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This function works on loading an external page inside of a div that passes a `$_POST` variable and click works on the first record on loading the same external page with `$_POST` variable from query.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
// load index page when the page loads
$("#form").load("tm-reserves-form.php");
$("#record").click(function(){
// load home page on click
    var ContactID = document.getElementById('ContactID').value;
    $("#form").load("tm-reserves-form.php", {"ContactID": ContactID});
    });
});
```

What is not functioning is this seems to only be passing the first record variable and no others. I can click on the first record and the external page with data loads. I click on other records and the div does not load with new data from click. I have a page that creates a customer list from a mysql query, inside the record loop is a hidden input field with the primary key. Any thoughts on what I am missing? I thought maybe to unbind click, but that did not work either.

HTML Code

```
<div id="record"><?php do { ?><input type="hidden" name="ContactID" id="ContactID" value="<?php echo $row_tm_reserves['ContactID']; ?>"><!-- Other strings --><?php } while ($row_tm_reserves = mysql_fetch_assoc($tm_reserves)); ?></div>
```

Help! and Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use the same ID over and over on the same page. Switch to classes.

Comment: Do you have an `id=ContactID` on every record? In valid HTML you should have unique IDs and anything else may cause problems.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Nice! Is that as easy as using getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @DerekManson is id's unique in the page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `#form` content gets **replaced** on every `load`.

**My solution:**

You can create a new element inside `#form`, for example a `<p>`, and `append` to it, i.e. :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").load("tm-reserves-form.php");
$(document).on("click","#record",function(){
    var ContactID = document.getElementById('ContactID').value;
    $("#form").append($(document.createElement("p")).load("tm-reserves-form.php", {"ContactID": ContactID}));
    });
});
```

Comment: Your solution revealed a new issue, seems that the first record ContactID is the only one being loaded in the external page.

Comment: Now to find out ... why?

Comment: What's the return value of `tm-reserves-form.php` ? It's difficult for me to see the big picture without the full code.

Comment: It's just a test page with echo of $_POST['ContactID']

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with `event delegation`, change

```
$("#record").click(function(){

});
```

to

```
$(document).on("click","#record",function(){

});
```

Mainly make sure you have only one `id` as `record` in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your html code, to help us help you...
if new dom elements are added, the script that attaches actions on them will not work, because they didnt exist at the load of that script.. switch to :

```
$(document).on("action","element",function()
```